# What role does corporate governance play with the practice of a Project Management Office?

Tags: project-team, project-management-style

Corporate governance is defined as `mechanisms, processes and relations by which corporations are controlled and directed` by `Wikipedia`.

- What role does it play when starting a Project Management Office?
- What role does it play in the project management style?

Comment: Governance is not a project, but projects must integrate with governance.

Comment: @CodeGnome - I understand that it is not a project. I am wanting to understand how corporate governance guides projects or the Project Management Office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None whatsoever.

Except for the fact that the PMO, like **all** company departments, must operate within the rules, practises and processes defined within Corporate Governance.

The exception would be if the project is actually delivering or working on the corporate governance.